# TLS ClientHello leaks HTTP host header

Tags: tls, privacy, man-in-the-middle

As already discussed on this platform, TLS Client Hello messages are not encrypted, since they contain "no sensitive data".
When sniffing HTTPS requests with wireshark, I can see the domain I am trying to access in the Client Hello packets though, which seems like sensitive data to me.

This behavior can also be observed by opening a netcat server on port 443 (or any other for that matter) and accessing "https://localhost" from a browser.

When surfing on a public hotspot for instance, I was expecting HTTPS to protect my privacy and prevent anyone from seeing what websites I am visiting. Sure, the IP address might be somewhat of a giveaway, but multiple websites might have the same IP.

So, finally, my question:
Shouldn't HTTPS or TLS protect the hostname I am trying to access from being unencrypted?

Comment: TLS 1.3 has the encrypted SNI (ESNI) extension to solve this problem.  See https://blog.cloudflare.com/encrypted-sni/ and https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/what-is-encrypted-sni/ for more info.  Bear in mind that the hostname that you are visiting may also be leaked when the browser does a DNS lookup for this hostname.  So, DoT or DoH should be used to prevent this.

Comment: Nitpick: TLS 1.3 doen not have ESNI. ESNI is an extension of TLS v1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is required for the implementation of multiple domain virtual hosting of webserver like NGINX. The server requires the presence of the host name in order to route the request to the correct server implementation. Only when it reaches the correct service can NGINX consult the TLS settings and then set up the encrypted session. So this value has to be transmitted in the clear.

There is some related discussion on the topic here https://serverfault.com/questions/1060208/is-the-host-header-required-over-ssl

Answer (score 3):

Encrypted-SNI (ESNI) is an extension of TLS 1.3 that encrypts the server name from the ClientHello message. This would be accomplished by encrypting the SNI extension using the server's public key and sending it to the server as ciphertext. The server would attempt to decrypt the ciphertext using the secret key corresponding to its public key and so on. In order to use ESNI to connect to a website, client would have to do a standard A/AAAA queries for a TXT record with the ESNI public key. SNI is encrypted, but if we leak the server name via plaintext DNS queries, what's the point? Deploying ESNI this way became feasible with the introduction of DNS-over-HTTPS (DoH), which enables encryption of DNS queries to resolvers that provide the DoH service (1.1.1.1 is an example of such a service.).

Encrypted Client-Hello (ECH) eliminates the shortcomings of ESNI by encrypting the entire ClientHello, thereby closing the gap left by TLS 1.3 and ESNI by protecting all privacy-sensitive parameters. For more info on this, look at this blog - https://blog.cloudflare.com/encrypted-client-hello/